# Convert dict into list ansible podman module expecting it

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I have following dict:

```
ports:
  http:
    host: 81
    container: 80
  https:
    host: 444
    container: 443
```

I want to use it in my role and partly because it works great for an example on this task (works as expected).

```
- name: ensure container's exposed ports firewall state
  tags: firewall
  firewalld:
    port: "{{ item.value.host }}/tcp"
    permanent: yes
    immediate: yes
    state: enabled
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', ports, wantlist=True) }}"
  when: ports is defined
```

But on the following task, the loop won't work (I tried to start a container with both ports enabled):

```
- name: Run container
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: "{{ container_name }}"
    image: "{{ container_image }}"
    state: "{{ state }}"
    recreate: "{{ recreate }}"
    ports: 
      - "{{ item.value.host }}:{{ item.value.container }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', ports, wantlist=True) }}"
```

If I do the loop with **loop** statement it will start two containers (one w/ http the other one w/ https) and with **with_items** it will only apply the last value (in this the case https).

The module expects the values like this. (w/ hardcoded values it worked in a test..)

```
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: myapplication
    ...
    ports:
        - "8080:9000"
        - "127.0.0.1:8081:9001/udp"
```

How can I transform my existing dict into a form the modules will expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping will call the module as many times you have items. Use the loop to create the list of ports before calling the module, e.g.

```yaml
- name: Calculate list of ports to launch container
  vars:
    current_port: "{{ item.value.host }}:{{ item.value.container }}"
  set_fact:
    port_list: "{{ port_list | default([]) + [current_port] }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', ports, wantlist=True) }}"

- name: Run container
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: "{{ container_name }}"
    image: "{{ container_image }}"
    state: "{{ state }}"
    recreate: "{{ recreate }}"
    ports: "{{ port_list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

the env vars

```
env_vars:
  hostname:
    key: HOSTNAME
    value: '"host1"'
  user:
    key: USER
    value: '"user1"'
```

i converted w/:

```
- name: Calculate list of env_vars to launch container
  set_fact:
    env_vars_dict: "{{ env_vars_dict|default({}) | combine( {item.value.key | upper: item.value.value} ) }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', env_vars, wantlist=True) }}"
```